# Get YUV instead of RGB at a pixel from a video in javascript

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas, shader

I have an incoming video which is encoded in YUV, I want to get Y value of a particular pixel from the incoming video.
But when I used getImageData() I got RGB value of that particular pixel.
When I searched on net about this I came across this answer [Access raw YUV values from JPEG with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215169/access-raw-yuv-values-from-jpeg-with-javascript.It) says that javascript automatically converts YUV to RGB when using getImageData(). Due to some performance issues I cant use any methods to convert RGB again back to YUV. Is there a way to avoid the automatic conversion from YUV to RGB and access the Y value of a particular pixel?

Comment: Did you see the comment on that question you linked to? What about that library doesn’t suit your needs? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215169/access-raw-yuv-values-from-jpeg-with-javascript/22215370#comment33779579_22215370

Comment: ya, but I cant use that because my incoming video is already in YUV , so it will be good if i could avoid the conversion to RGB  @Ben Steward

Comment: Is that because you’re trying to do this in a browser?

Comment: I reopened this question, even though I'm not sure enough of what an answer should be for now. Accessing a particular pixel at a particular time of a video has almost nothing to do with accessing a pixel of a still jpeg image. And things might change in the near future wrt [colorspace management in canvas API](https://github.com/WICG/canvas-color-space/blob/master/CanvasColorSpaceProposal.md)